# Method that handles exceptions from BeginInvoke?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Sometime you need to run specific code on specific threads, for example winforms. To get the code running on the UI thread you need something like this :

```
this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
{
   try
   {
       //code
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       HandleException(ex);
   }
}
```

SynchornixationContext is another way to do the same thing.

Say that we know that we need to run specific code in the UI thread and we have a given way of handling the exceptions that are thrown on this UI thread(BeginInvoke is not blocking so exceptions will not be transfered). How could we create a method that makes the same thing but simplier like this :

```
RunOnUIThread(MyMethod);
```

The RunOnUIThread will contains mor or less the same code as the first example in this code.

Is it possible to create a method like this? And if so How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write some nice extension methods like this

```
public static class ControlExtension
{
    public static IAsyncResult BeginInvokeWithExceptionHandling(this Control control, Action method, Action<Exception> exceptionHandler)
    {
        if (control == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("control");
        if (method == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("method");
        if (exceptionHandler == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("exceptionHandler");

        return control.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                method();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                exceptionHandler(ex);
            }
        }));
    }

    public static IAsyncResult BeginInvokeWithExceptionHandling<T>(this Control control, Delegate method, Action<Exception> exceptionHandler, params object[] args)
    {
        if (control == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("control");
        if (method == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("method");
        if (exceptionHandler == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("exceptionHandler");

        return control.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                method.DynamicInvoke(args);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                exceptionHandler(ex);
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
private void HandleException(Exception ex)
{

}

private void MyMethod()
{

}

this.BeginInvokeWithExceptionHandling(MyMethod, HandleException);
```

Note: Due to `Delegate.DynamicInvoke` this may be little less performing, you can fix it with strong typed delegate. It is also worth noting that `control.BeginInvoke` is also internally using `Delegate.DynamicInvoke` if it can't find what the delegate type is.

Comment: Thanks, but its still to much code, I want to just call RunOnUIThread(MyMethod);

Comment: You can certainly do that, but what you want to do when there is an exception?

Comment: I need to run the same code as in my first example. So try/catch and within the catch handle the exception(this case log to database)

Comment: @Banshee Updated my answer, to make it still less code.

Comment: Nice, thanks alot! I will try it as soon as possible.

Comment: Im trying to use this with the SynchronizationContext.Post instead of Control.BeginInvoke but SynchronizationContext do not return any IAsyncResult?

Comment: @Banshee Nope, it doesn't.

Comment: Would it be possible to use the SynchronizationContext.Post with the code above? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void InvokeControlAction<t>(t cont, Action<t> action) where t : Control
{
    if (cont.InvokeRequired)
    { cont.Invoke(new Action<t, Action<t>>(InvokeControlAction), 
                new object[] { cont, action }); }
    else
    { action(cont); }
}
```

[CodeProject Reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37413/A-Generic-Method-for-Cross-thread-Winforms-Access)

Comment: Thanks, but its still to much code, I want to just call RunOnUIThread(MyMethod);

Answer (score 0):

I ended upp with this based on Sriram´s suggestion :

```
public static void SendToUIThread(Action method, bool UseExceptionHandling = true)
        {
            if (method == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("method is missing");

            _threadSyncContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback(delegate(object state)
            {
                if (UseExceptionHandling)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        method();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ErrorController.Instance.LogAndDisplayException(ex, true);
                    }
                }
                else
                    method();

            }), null);
        }

        public static void PostOnUIThread(this Control control, Action method, bool UseExceptionHandling = true)
        {
            if (method == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("method is missing");

            if (control.InvokeRequired)
                PostOnUIThread(method, UseExceptionHandling);
            else
            {
                if (UseExceptionHandling)
                {
                    try { method(); }
                    catch (Exception ex) { ErrorController.Instance.LogAndDisplayException(ex, true); }
                }
                else
                    method();
            }
        }
```